# how to change mm/dd/yy to yy/mm/dd in vba, I can change the format but it doesn't change the value of the cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have cells that have dates in the format mm/dd/yy, how can I change the cell to yy/mm/dd in vba, I tried using `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(11, 4).NumberFormat = "yy/mm/dd"` but it doesn't change the value of the cell.

Comment: what value is in the cell? and is it on the first worksheet in cells(11,4)?

Comment: It has 01/02/15   and I am trying to make it  15/01/02

Comment: its always 8 characters in the cell if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the format of a cell and the displayed value does not respond, then the value is *Text* rather than a true *Date*.  To fix this:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim s As String, d As Date
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(11, 4)
        s = .Text
        d = DateValue(s)
        .Clear
        .Value = d
        .NumberFormat = "yy/mm/dd"
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

To do this with pure strings:

```
Sub dural2()
    Dim s As String
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(11, 4)
        s = Trim(.Text)
        ary = Split(s, "/")
        .NumberFormat = "@"
        .Value = ary(2) & "/" & ary(0) & "/" & ary(1)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi I tried this but it gives me an error (type mismatch) on  d =DateValue(s)

Comment: @Dean  Are you sure the cell contain stuff like *12/25/15* with **no additional spaces** ??

Comment: yes, and I m just wondering is there a way to do it as a string and just change the order within the cell?

Comment: @Dean  To do this with strings only, see my **EDIT#1**